# Service layer mocked in controller class is executing actual method implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4, mockmvc

When writing the unit test case for the controller class, I mocked the service layer call to return the desired value, but instead, it returns null.

## Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class ControllerTest {

        @Mock
        private Service serviceMock;

        @InjectMocks
        private Controller controller;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        /**
         * Sets the up.
         *
         * @throws Exception the exception
         */
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockMvc = 
    MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void method1() throws Exception {
            when(this.serviceMock.associateTag(any(Request.class), null))
            .thenReturn(Responses.SUCCESS);
    mockMvc.perform(post("/tag/assign").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(request))               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
        }
```

## Controller Class

```
@PostMapping("/assign")
public RestResponse assignTag(@RequestBody final TagAssociation 
tagAssociation) {
final TagResponses serviceResponse = 
this.service.associateTag(tagOrderAssociation, null);
```

serviceResponse is always null, I was expecting an enum response Responses.SUCCESS

## Stack Trace

testException = org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

The Service layer has many dependencies autowired.
do I need to mock it as well?
Not able to figure out the exact reason for failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using matchers while stubbing, you have to use them for all of the input params. So try:

```
when(this.serviceMock.associateTag(Mockito.any(Request.class), Mockito.eq(null)))
```

If you would like a further read then I wrote this article on [Mockito Stubbing](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/unit-testing/mockito-stubbing/20)